# Give each Post instance a custom order position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Post` model.

I would like to specify on a "post-by-post" basis their order.

I assume a `position:integer` attribute is a good start.

This is an example what would be rendered with `Post.order(position: :asc)`:

```
id: 3, position: 1
id: 2, position: 2
id: 8, position: 3
...
```

But how would the update procedure be done then? Or any other, better ideas?

Comment: `Post.order(id: :asc)` ?

Comment: I'm sorry that would only order them by their ID, I need to control the position more specifically.

Comment: You can use the [ActsAsList](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem to handle the update procedure, no need to reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have the `position` attribute set for all your records. You should, by the way, make sure it cannot be nil:

```
change_column :posts, :position, :integer, null: false
```

Say you have a `Post` which currently is the 9th post and needs to be the 5th post.

First, you need to temporarily 'remove' the post from the position list. All posts with position 10 and higher need to be decremented by one:

```
Post.where('position > ?', 9).update_all('position = position - 1')
```

Then you need to put it back into the position list. This is done by incrementing all the positions from the current fifth position onwards:

```
Post.where('position >= ?', 5).update_all('position = position + 1')
```

This whole procedure involves two database queries, and you don't load tons of ActiveRecord objects into memory.

You could make this an `before_update` callback like this:

```
class Post
  before_create :update_positions
  before_update :update_positions, if: :position_changed?

  def update_positions
    if position_was
      Post.where('position > ?', position_was).update_all('position = position - 1')
    end
    Post.where('position >= ?' position).update_all('position = position + 1')
  end
end
```

The obvious last part it to order it by position whenever you display posts:

```
Post.all.order(:position)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Two questions though: 1) Where and how do you set the `position_was` value? 2) Why the gap between 5 and 9 in your example?

Comment: The gap is just for illustration purposes, no special meaning. In the example I'm changing the order of an existing post. `position_was` contains the previous value of the position value. Rails does this for you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html. Notice that by checking if `position_was` has been set, I determine whether or not to remove the post from the position list first.

Comment: Both `.transaction` and  `_was` was new to me, thanks for the enlightment (and the thorough answer).

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. It now uses the `before_*` callbacks rather than `after_*` to make sure the whole thing works properly. Also, the transaction block is unnecessary, since the whole create and update operations themselves are already wrapped into a database transaction! :)